# UIButton with circle frame and number in it

Tags: swift, uibutton

I want to make a button with a circle frame like the default iOS one in lock screen where you enter your passcode to unlock the iPhone. I have tried it with custom UIButton class but no matter what I did title (the numbers 0,1,2...) wasn't showing in the buttons (circle buttons empty inside). I do not want to repeat the same code for each 10 buttons. I am working with swift.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try something like this.

```
            let numberButton = UIButton(type: .System)
            numberButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100 , 100 )
            numberButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
            numberButton.layer.cornerRadius = numberButton.frame.size.width / 2
            numberButton.clipsToBounds = true
            numberButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20/255, green: 20/255, blue: 20/255, alpha: 0.7) //Here you can change background color
            numberButton.alpha = 1
            numberButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "1", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(25),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]) , forState: .Normal) //Here you can change the number
            numberButton.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
            self.view.addSubview(numberButton)
```